# Illegal invocation Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, live

I only have one function in my scripts page, and it is giving me this error: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation.  To be honest, I've never seen this error before, and none of the other cases that I found online seemed to apply to me.  My jquery is below, and I don't think any other pieces are necessary, but let me know and I can post other parts.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    /*----UPDATE BOX REQUEST----*/
    $(".boxesChange").live("click", function () {
        entry = $(this).closest("tr");
        delivered = $(entry).find("#delivered");
        if ((delivered).is(":checked")) {
            deliveredBoolean = "1";
        } else {
            deliveredBoolean = "0";
        }
        boxesDelivered = $(entry).find("#boxesDelivered").val();
        bubbleWrapDelivered = $(entry).find("#bubbleWrapDelivered").val();
        supplyRequestId = $(entry).find(".boxesSupplyRequestId").val();

        $.post('boxesChange.php', {
            'delivered': delivered,
            'boxesDelivered': boxesDelivered,
            'bubbleWrapDelivered': bubbleWrapDelivered,
            'supplyRequestId': supplyRequestId
        }, function (response) {
            $(this).closest(".boxesScheduleEntry").css("background-color", "#ccffcc");
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Is it weird that you use `'delivered': delivered` when `delivered` is a jQuery object? Maybe you should do `delivered:  delivered.is(":checked") ? 1 : 0` or use your `deliveredBoolean` thing?

Comment: @jamund I'm not sure I understand where you are putting that exactly

Comment: @radleybobins: In your `$.post` call.

Comment: [Rocket](http://stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket) means in the parameters passed to $.post... here you have `'delivered': delivered,` which obviously should deliver the `deliveredBoolean` value and not the content of the `delivered` Object... so try to do `'delivered': deliveredBoolean,`

Comment: Ah, I see, that got rid of the error, thanks!  If you change that to an answer, I can mark it as correct, thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `$.post` call.  You're trying to set `'delivered'` to `delivered`, which is a jQuery object, I assume you meant `deliveredBoolean`.

Also, in the callback function `this` is not what you think it is, it's the jqXHR object, not the element.

```
var $this = $(this);
$.post(
        'boxesChange.php', 
        {
            'delivered': deliveredBoolean,
            'boxesDelivered': boxesDelivered,
            'bubbleWrapDelivered': bubbleWrapDelivered,
            'supplyRequestId': supplyRequestId
        },
        function (response) {
            $this.closest(".boxesScheduleEntry").css("background-color", "#ccffcc");
        }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume the error is inside of this part:

```
function (response) {
  $(this).closest(".boxesScheduleEntry").css("background-color", "#ccffcc");
}
```

Here I think you want `this` to be the same as above when you are using closest to get the "tr" element. But in here `this` is the context of the $.post imho.

You either need to bind or rather do `var boxChange = $(this),` at the top of the event handler function and use the cached reference afterwards

Comment: That was a good thought, but I took the line out completely and the problem persisted.